# Prompt inside a function

Tags: javascript

SO i am new to coding. So basically I am wondering whether it is possible to have prompt inside a function. AN example of my code is below:

```
var userName = function(name) {
   var n = prompt("Whats your name?");
   console.log(n)
};
```

I also want to print out the name that is going to be inputted. 
Thanks

Comment: Looks fine.  What doesn't work about it?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the code you have?

Comment: i was trying to have print out the answer given to the prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could do something like this:

```
var userName = function(){
    return prompt("Whats your name?");
};

console.log(userName());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mskf3mu1/

Answer (score 0):

Declare function like this `function PromptName()
{ 
var name = prompt('what's your name'); return name;
}`
then call this function inside another `var name = PromptName();`